# Google Reaptcha v3 still letting spam through

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I just added Google Recaptcha V3 to a site and a lot of spam is still getting through. I know that Google needs to build up some traffic on the site to determine if something is spam. How long should that take? Like if this is still happening after X days there is a problem? What is X?

Here is how I implemented this. On the client side I get the token:

```
function validateCaptcha(form, callback) {
    $("#captcha-error").addClass('hidden');
    $("#captcha-error").hide();
    $("#captcha-error").html('');

    var formName = $('#formName').val();
    if (!formName) formName = 'AmeriGasGenericForm';
    var siteKey = $('#siteKey').val();

    if (grecaptcha) {
        try {
            grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                grecaptcha.execute(siteKey, { action: formName }).then(function(token) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/recaptcha-validate?recaptchaResponse=" + token + "&actionName=" + formName,
                        async: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log("score:" + response.score);
                            if (response.Success == false) {
                                $("#captcha-error").html('Unable to verify reCAPTCHA. Please try again.');
                                $("#captcha-error").removeClass('hidden');
                                $("#captcha-error").show();
                            } else {
                                callback(form);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

That calls a server side check to validate:

```
public JsonNetResult ValidateRecaptcha(string recaptchaResponse, string actionName)
{
    var result = new RecaptchaResult();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaResponse))
    {
        result.Success = false;
        return new JsonNetResult(result);
    }

    var secretKey = Settings.GetSetting("reCAPTCHA.Secret");
    var url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + recaptchaResponse;

    var recaptchaThresholdString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reCaptchaThreshold"];
    if (!float.TryParse(recaptchaThresholdString, out var threshold))
    {
        threshold = 0.5f;
    }

    using (var reCaptchaHttpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var reCaptchaResponseString = reCaptchaHttpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecaptchaResponseModel>(reCaptchaResponseString);
            result.Score = response.score;

            if (response.Success && response.score >= threshold && string.Equals(response.action, actionName,
                StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                result.Success = true;
            else
                result.Success = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Success = false;
        }
    }

    return new JsonNetResult(result);
}
```

I have the threshold set to allow anything higher than .5 through. But, when I look at the reCaptcha admin console in Google, like 99% of the requests are scored at .9. So Im not sure what to do here to prevent spam. It seems recaptcha thinks everything is a human but when I look at actual submissions I am receiving, they are clearly spam.

Comment: What kind of spam?  Bc I am using it in Wordpress and Kentico site, it is working correctly for me. I tried using Selenium to test it.

Comment: The spam has basically random content in all fields.